# defining the (cw/ccw) in radians (pos/neg)

Tags: education

are there any negative radians?

```
    **deg°  0.0  32.9       /-32.9
    **rad*  0.0   0.5742133 / -0.5742133
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ca8WJ.png)

Comment: Yes, negative radians, just like degrees means a clockwise turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually associate $x$ degrees to an anticlockwise rotation if $x$ is positive and to a clockwise rotation if $x$ is negative. The same applies to radians, with the relation $180$ degrees equals $\pi$ radians.

Comment: thank you guys!  i kinda felt this was tru but need to be sure so a little confirmation is always a good thing.

Comment: why can i convert this neg deg into a neg rad ?

`float deg = −3.5;`

i get this when i try to run this deg as a float ,whats the issue? i have calculated a float negative deg = -144.3; but i cant do −3.5?

`processing.app.SketchException: unexpected char: '\'`